# Inheritance and collection of objects

Tags: .net, vb.net, class, inheritance, collections

i  have a basic question.

lets say we have 3 classes:

```
Class S, class A, class B
A and B inherits S.
```

A has a property A1 and B has a property B1.

we also have a collection of objects that has A and B objects.

```
ex. 
Dim c as Collection = new Collection
c.add(new A)
c.add(new B)
```

Now we want to make a general object that will read from the collection.

```
ex .
Dim  obj as S
```

how can we cast obj in order to see properties A1 or B1 according to the class;

Comment: i'm not sure what exactly you want to do. For a simple cast use `CType(param, Type)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [TypeOf](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ec5kw18%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) to test the object type before casting although [TryCast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zyy863x8.aspx) might be better depending on what you want to do. Also take a look at [DirectCast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7k6y2h6x.aspx).

Comment: now that i am reconsidering it. you have right. i need first to deterimin the type of object before use the correct property.